# How to reload a dynamic content using script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an page which contains dynamic data, I'm trying to reload particular `<p></p>` only.

HTML

```
<p id="spa<?php echo $id; ?>"></p>
```

My script is something like this

```
$("#spa" + id).load(location.href + " #spa" + id);
```

But it's not working, any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't do anything as... `:S` Nice code tho! I feel this has a problem: `<p id="spa<?php echo id?>"></p>` Shouldn't it be `$id`?

Comment: :) no thats typo error.. happened now..

Comment: Try using no cache control in PHP.

Comment: You want to change the content of ```<p></p>``` or ID attribute value of it  ?

Comment: can we use the script like i used above? i feel that may contain error.

Answer (score 0):

Following shows how to add a new script tag to  with the script to reload

```html
<script language="text/javascript">
   function load_js()
   {
      var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= 'source_file.js';
      head.appendChild(script);
   }
   load_js();
</script>
```

The main point is inserting a new script tag -- you can remove the old one without consequence. You may need to add a timestamp to the query string if you have caching issues.

Comment: go to tis link http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97629/html-and-js-to-dynamically-load-refresh-and-execute-javascript-from-external-f @PattatharasuNataraj

Comment: let me know , is that works or not ? @PattatharasuNataraj

Comment: sure bro im trying... let u know once im finished