# JavaScript error while assigning a value to script tag src attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a word in my between by src using JavaScript, by getting that word from another div element. Running it results in the following error:

> Cannot set property 'src' of null`
>   Here's my code:

```html
<html><head></head><body>
<div id='content'></div>
<script>
function handleResponse(response) {
  var post_number  = Object.keys(response.items).length; //number of posts
  for (i=0; i<post_number; i++) { 
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<div class='posts'><h1>" + response.items[i].title + "</h1>" + response.items[i].content + '</div>';
      
  }
}
</script>
<div id='myImg'>Lists</div>
<script id='demo' src=""></script>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML;
var y= document.getElementById("demo"); y.src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/5039479718685240371/posts?labels="+x+"&callback=handleResponse&key=AIzaSyDxfWmXTRnO5yIp25NvuUEBWKSa_5mqjHA";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try this instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483802/3214471

Comment: When you check the snippet you posted with your question, the behavior you described is not reproduced.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

Comment: @Rajesh can you make it work for me?

Comment: @AjayMalik Would like to help but as per error, you are not getting the element. If you have exact same code, it should work, but you can try `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ /* Your code here */ })`. This will enforce your code to run once DOM is rendered and loaded

Comment: @Rajesh window.addEventListener attaching src to script, but script content are still not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML;
    var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
    s.setAttribute('src', "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/5039479718685240371/posts?labels=" + x + "&callback=handleResponse&key=AIzaSyDxfWmXTRnO5yIp25NvuUEBWKSa_5mqjHA");
    document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah! it worked! Can You explain me why my code didn't work

Comment: Just a pointer, its a bad practice to answer a duplicate post. If you know the solution, you are likely to find better dupe and you should close it. Since you do not have enough rep, you can add it comment and someone will close it. In general, its always better to close as old posts have other ways and lot of discussion

Comment: @Rajesh sure... :)

Comment: @Rajesh i think you already make it duplicate, i din;t checked.

Comment: @GiteshPurbia It was a general comment. Lets try to follow from next time :-) Have a good day

Comment: @AjayMalik because you're changing script src only, script is not going to execute again when you are changing its src,so try to create a new script tag and append it to body.

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute

Comment: Thanks! for your help